# Flutter widget (Padding) constructor error (1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.)

Tags: flutter, padding, flutter-layout

Today I was going to work further on my app, but I saw that an error appeared that I was not having before. Flutter can't seem to create a padding Widget.

I've searched for any ';' or ',' I missed, but everything seems alright. If I go to the official documentation and copy-paste an example it does not work.

This error happens all over my project, I think something is bugging

**Code where error occurs**

```
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7.0),
  child: TextField(
    autofocus: true,
    controller: _searchQueryController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Text over here',
      prefixIcon: new Padding(
        padding: // <<=== error
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: new Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Error**
1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

Comment: Try killing the dartanalyzer with the red circle in the "Dart Analysis" view if you use Android Studio or IntelliJ. Don't know how it looks in VSCode. The code doesn't show any errors in my IDE.

Comment: Did not help, I did a checked out on a branch which I'm sure does work and it is also giving this error, `flutter analyze` is giving me the same error.
Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.254]

Comment: Try deleting  `~/.dartServer/.analysis-driver/`. I don't know what the equivalent Windows path is though.

Comment: Deleted the folder (was 1GB), restarted the IDE (folder was re-created, 20MB). Problem is still occurring.
This is what VSCode is saying: [link](https://ibb.co/mNrj9e) 
It's like the constructor of the Padding widget has changed and we can't use the named '{padding}' property to pass the EdgeInset

Comment: Weird. The screenshot shows a required `padding` and a named optional `padding`. The same code works at the first line in your code example above.

Comment: So how could I do further research on this topic, because atm I can't compile the code. I tried to fill in the constructor like this:

    Padding(
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
It does give me no error, but when I do `flutter run` it gives an error.

Comment: No idea. perhaps your Flutter installation is somehow corrupted. You could try `git clean -xfd` `git pull` `flutter doctor` in the Flutter install directory.

Comment: Too bad, this did not solve anything. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: **Solution:** I deleted the flutter SDK and re-installed the SDK. The `git clean -xfd` `git pull` did not work. So it is a must to delete the flutter folder (in my case it was `c:\flutter`.